# Why this SQL query would make any user log in to system without vaild password?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am learning PHP and SQL injection. In a tutorial it says:

> If un-escaped the query sent to MySQL would be:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='aidan' AND password='' OR ''=''
> ```

This would allow anyone to log in without a valid password. Could anyone let me know why the above query would allow anyone to log in without a valid password?

Comment: `''=''` is TRUE.  They are doing `OR TRUE`.  Therefore the entire clause is TRUE.

Comment: P.S. Use prepared statements.  With prepared statements SQL injection (and needing to escape strings) becomes a thing of the past! :-D

Comment: and scrub your input to only safe characters.

Comment: thx Rocket. Does this query equals to SELECT * FROM users ?

Comment: yes it does because `user='aidan' AND password='' OR ''=''` is always true (think of it as `(user='aidan' AND password='') OR ''=''`)

Comment: @bean: Pretty much, yeah.

Comment: Thanks DrCopyPaste and Rocket!

Comment: Instead of "scrub your input to only safe characters", learn to use parameterized queries that take care of it for you.